# A complete list of the CSS properties that can be animated through jQuery animate()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I've been using jQuery's wonderful animate() function recently, but I've found that only a portion of CSS properties can be animated through jQuery.

I've checked the jQuery [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), but it doesn't give a list of all the possible properties that can be animated. It even states that some properties can only be animated with certain files, such as the jQuery UI file.

So do you guys have a list, perhaps somewhere in the Internet, of all the CSS properties that can be animated through jQuery? It would be even more helpful if you mention which ones require specific files/CDN.

**EDIT**
**Okay, so I learned that any CSS property with numeric values can be animated. So is it possible to animate non-numeric CSS properties?**

Like if you want to turn one font-family into another smoothly (which sounds very difficult) or animate overflow:visible to overflow:hidden?

Comment: It's pretty clear on the docs  **allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property**

Comment: Mind blown. I didn't even know that any numeric CSS property can be animated. Thanks man! I'll try to rephrase my question then.

Comment: They don't give a list but they explain on the docs under the line **Animation Properties and Values** how it works and where it works

Comment: What would be the halfway state between `overflow:visible` and `overflow:hidden?`?

Answer (score 2):

This page has a list, I haven't tried them all out though.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

- backgroundPositionX
- backgroundPositionY
- borderWidth
- borderBottomWidth
- borderLeftWidth
- borderRightWidth
- borderTopWidth
- borderSpacing
- margin
- marginBottom
- marginLeft
- marginRight
- marginTop
- outlineWidth
- padding
- paddingBottom
- paddingLeft
- paddingRight
- paddingTop
- height
- width
- maxHeight
- maxWidth
- minHeight
- minWidth
- fontSize
- bottom
- left
- right
- top
- letterSpacing
- wordSpacing
- lineHeight
- textIndent

Comment: I don't see color and opacity, and I remember that those require the jQuery UI file.

Comment: It's what they claim to be 'animatable' properties. I would try them out just to be sure. The question comes up right away in a google search.